# Как добавлять +1 число с каждой итерацией?

Tags: javascript

В функции создал переменную, которая будет хранить сумму необходимых порций для гостей,
Создал цикл for от 1 до numberOfGuests
На каждой итерации цикла увеличиваю sum на текущее количество
После цикла возвращаю переменную, которая была создана в начале (sum)

```
 function getDrinks(numberOfGuests) {
   let sum = 0;
   for(let sum = 1; sum <= numberOfGuests; sum++ ){
     sum = numberOfGuests;
     console.log(sum)
   }
   return sum;
 }
 getDrinks(12);
```

Comment: Вы в итерацию цикла присваиваете максимальное значение сразу.. тоесть цикл выполнится 1 раз... вы уверены, что именно это вам нужно?
З.Ы. сужу по коду, так как описание к нему не дает нужной информации

Comment: Нужно что бы вышло (1+2+3+4...и.т.п)

Comment: Большое спасибо, изучу!

Answer (score 3):

Изучите пару уроков по алгоритмам и JS, Вы пока что не понимаете, как Ваш код работает.

- Не используйте для счетчика суммы то же название, что и для счетчика
  цикла.
- В цикле прибавляйте к существующему числу единицу (в js это
  `sum += 1` или `sum++` или `sum = sum + 1`).
- Не записывайте общее число (`numberOfGuests`) сразу – это приведет к тому, что Ваш цикл будет работать вхолостую, а на реальной задаче Вы не получите верный результат (например, если в цикле число надо умножать на 4, то в результате Вы всё равно получите изначальное число аргумента).

Примерно это должно быть так:

```js
function getDrinks(numberOfGuests) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfGuests; i++) {
    sum++;
    console.log(sum)
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(`Result: ${getDrinks(12)}`);
```